# MS Excel SQL Query via ADO

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, ado.net

I have a problem that I have been attempting to solve all morning, and it is really beginning to bug me. Can anyone help?

In short: A "simple" SQL query pulling in info from an Access .MDB into MS Excel.

I can get ALL of the following THREE queries to work without problem:

- `SELECT * from Table WHERE (Area = 255);`
- `SELECT * from Table WHERE (Area = ?);`
- `SELECT * from Table WHERE (Area BAND 255);`

However, can I get the following to work?

- `SELECT * from Table WHERE (Area BAND ?);`

Whatever I do, I can't get the Parameter setting configured to reference from cell A1 (the parameters box is greyed out).
I know (think) that this has to be an ADO connection (or in ANSI 92 query mode).

PLEASE can someone show me how to do this.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Rather than using bullet points you can make something code by using \` Ie \`code\` `code`